# Find all solutions of the equation in the interval $[0, 2π)$: $7\sec^2(x)−7\sec(x) = 14$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help to find all solutions of the equation in the interval [0, 2π).
Could you give me some directions?

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Can you share some thoughts? My thought is that I see a quadratic equation

Comment: Solve the quadratic: $7x^2 - 7x - 14 = 0$...then find which solutions satisfy $x = \sec(\theta)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  7(\sec x)^2- 7 \sec x = 14 \implies (\sec x)^2 - \sec x - 2 = 0
$$
By factoring, $(\sec x - 2)(\sec x + 1) = 0$, so...